# Are 7490N & 74LS190N Same IC's?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, clock, counter

As mentioned above, are 7490N & 74LS190N Same IC's? Im a bit confused about these two. Please tell me their name(s) too.

Comment: Their names? Didn't you just....

Comment: Have you Googled them?

Answer (score 4):

Nope... different families, different function, different pin count, different chips. They are both counters, but different kinds and that's about it.

[7490](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls90.pdf) [74LS190](http://www.futurlec.com/74LS/74LS190.shtml)

Comment: Thankyou Everyone! :)

Comment: Oh nooooo :( Bought them now and now im regretting :(

Answer (score 3):

They are both IC's from the 74ls family. However, the 90 counts up while the 190 can count up and down.

Their names would be "74ls90" and "74ls190". The lettering before and after that is just to let you know what kind of chip it is. Like weather it's a surface mount or through hole, etc.

This is based on my minimal understanding of these chips.

[Here](http://www.elab.ph/forum/index.php?topic=4543.0) is where I figured that

Comment: 7490 and 74ls90 are not the same. Logically yes but electrically no.

Comment: Yah I just read a little more and realized that. I was assuming he meant logically and not electrically. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Not even logically.  Usually, all you have to do is look at datasheet to see similar devices.

Comment: 7490 and 74ls90 are logically the same, 7490 and 74ls190 aren't.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to get at is that the 74ls90 and 7490 are identical logically, while the 74ls190 is not